# Override global query results without hooks

Tags: plugins, loop, globals

I have a custom php page and i need to override the global posts variables, but i cant get it to work. When going through the main loop im able to override the global posts, but i cant override whatever have_posts() is using to obtain the count. Im obtaining data from a 3rd party API so i need to build the WP object on the fly and then override the default objects returned from the default query. I have the following code and its working, but the problem is that i get a result that contains the post and then several null objects afterwards.

```
require_once('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

global $post, $posts, $found_posts, $post_count;

$post->ID = 99999999999;
$post->post_content = "TEST PAGE content";
$post->post_title = "Page Title";
$post->post_name = "test";

$posts = array($post);
$post_count = 1;
$found_posts = 1;

if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        var_dump($post);
    }
}
```

The above code generates the following output. I need to get rid of the NULLs. To do this i need to make it so have_posts() only returns true once.

> object(WP_Post)#2975 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(99999999999)
>   ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2016-01-21
>   19:50:24" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-01-21 19:50:24"
>   ["post_content"]=> string(17) "TEST PAGE content" ["post_title"]=>
>   string(10) "Page Title" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6)
>   "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(4) "test" ["to_ping"]=> string(0)
>   "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19)
>   "2016-01-21 19:50:24" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-01-21
>   19:50:24" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=>
>   int(0) ["guid"]=> string(36) "" ["menu_order"]=> int(0)
>   ["post_type"]=> string(4) "page" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } NULL
>   NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL

Comment: You are just doing it wrong. Don't populate $post by yourself and if your design calls for it then it is probably broken.

Comment: I'm not calling the wp dB though I can't use wp query as the data comes from a different location

Comment: As I said, it means you have a bad design. $post is a wordpress API object which have assumed side effects, you are just likely to get into trouble by trying to do all the things that need to be done by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this was in the $wp_query variable. By getting the global variable for this and overriding the values within it i was able to have full control over what displayed on the page. This allowed me to generate a WP post object that came from a database outside of wordpress, but didnt have to do anything difficult to make it display.

Here is a full guide that explains how to do it http://yomotherboard.com/how-to-add-a-custom-php-page-to-wordpress-using-a-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

It is quite hard to understand what you need to do here, but you need to look at the following

- Do not use the global variables as local variables, it breaks the global variables and causes issues with the loop. It is also quite hard to debug when you run into issues. The only global variable that should be used as a local variable is when you work with `setup_postdata()`. `setup_postdata()` requires the `$post` global. You just need to remember to reset the `$post` global afterwards.
- Use the actions and filters available inside `WP_Query` to change the result from a specific query object

In general, the `$post_count` property is calculated from the amount of posts inside `$posts`. Just before posts are counted, we get the `the_posts` filter. This allows us to add/remove post objects (*or rearrange the post order*) from the `$posts` array. Any alteration here in the amount of posts will result in the `$post_count property being altered

Here is the relevant code from the `WP_Query` class

```
if ( ! $q['suppress_filters'] ) {
    /**
     * Filter the array of retrieved posts after they've been fetched and
     * internally processed.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     *
     * @param array    $posts The array of retrieved posts.
     * @param WP_Query &$this The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
     */
    $this->posts = apply_filters_ref_array( 'the_posts', array( $this->posts, &$this ) );
}
// Ensure that any posts added/modified via one of the filters above are
// of the type WP_Post and are filtered.
if ( $this->posts ) {
    $this->post_count = count( $this->posts );
    $this->posts = array_map( 'get_post', $this->posts );
    if ( $q['cache_results'] )
        update_post_caches($this->posts, $post_type, $q['update_post_term_cache'], $q['update_post_meta_cache']);
    $this->post = reset( $this->posts );
} else {
    $this->post_count = 0;
    $this->posts = array();
}
```

If you want to add a post into the array of posts returned, this will be the place to do it

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', function ( $posts, \WP_Query $q )
{
    if ( !$q->is_main_query ) // Only target the main query, return if not. Add any additional conditions
        return $posts;

    $post_to_add = [
        // Valid post properties
    ]; 

    $post_to_add = array_map( 'get_post', $post_to_add );

    // Add some checks to make sure our $post_to_inject is a valid.

    // Add $post_to_add in front of $posts array
    $posts = array_merge( $post_to_add, $posts );

    // If you need to replace $posts with your object
    //$posts = [$post_to_add];

    return $posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

`$post` gets set from the first post in the `$posts` array, so there is also no need to fiddle with that.

As for `$found_posts` you can make use of the `found_posts` filter to adjust the amount of posts found

```
add_filter( 'found_posts', function ( $found_posts, \WP_Query $q )
{
        if ( !$q->is_main_query ) // Only target the main query, return if not. Add any additional conditions
            return $found_posts;

    $found_posts = 1; // Taken info from your question

    return $found_posts;
}):
```

As I said, I'm not particulary sure what you need to do, but I hope I did touch the point you are after